# Firebase append data to node

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I append data to a node in Firebase? The value update would just be a string, not a dictionary.

Firebase should be able to increment each items. I thought `update` would work, but that only updates a dictionary. When I attempt to set the value, it erases everything.

```
FIRDatabase().reference().database.childRef(refUrl: path).updateChildValues([:])
```

Example:

```
node{
      1:itemOne
      2:itemTwo
      3:itemThree
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From firebase docs

*`https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write`*

*`Update specific fields
To simultaneously write to specific children of a node without overwriting other child nodes, use the updateChildValues method.`*

try something like

```
let key = ref.child("node").childByAutoId().key
let post = ["uid": userID,
            "author": username,
            "title": title,
            "body": body]
let childUpdates = ["/posts/\(key)": post,
                    "/user-posts/\(userID)/\(key)/": post]
ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```